# Typescript generic type param not working as expected when used as Index in mapped Types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am unable to understand typescript behaviour when accessing mapped types using a generic param, here the simplest code that triggers an error:

```
export type mockInstances = {
  app: {
    id: number;
    code: string;
  };
  setup: {
    id: number;
    code: string;
  };
};

type MockEntityName = keyof mockInstances;

type MockInstance<EntityName extends MockEntityName> =
  mockInstances[EntityName];

const testWrapper = <EntityName extends MockEntityName>() => {
  //Errors
  const a: Partial<MockInstance<EntityName>> = {
    id: 1,
  };
  const b: Partial<MockInstances[EntityName]> = {
    id: 2,
  };
  console.log('ab', a, b);

  //Error: Type '{ id: 1; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<MockInstance<EntityName>>'.ts(2322)

  //Works
  const c: Partial<MockInstance<'app'>> = {
    id: 1,
  };
  const d: Partial<MockInstances['app']> = {
    id: 2,
  };

  const e: Partial<MockInstances[mockEntityName]> = {
    id: 2,
  };

  console.log('cde', c, d, e);
};
```

I was expecting the typescript compiler to be able to have **a** and **b** "assignable" to the indexed type using the EntityName param (as index or type param).

Here an even simplified version of the the weird typescript behaviour:

```
export type mockInstances = {
  setup: {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    entityName: string;
    desc: string;
  };
};

type MockInstance<EntityName extends 'setup'> = mockInstances[EntityName];

const testWrapper = <EntityName extends 'setup'>(entityName: EntityName) => {
  //Error: Type '{ id: 1; code: "test"; entityName: EntityName; }'
  // is not assignable to type 'Partial<MockInstance<EntityName>>'.ts(2322)
  const a: Partial<MockInstance<EntityName>> = {
    id: 1,
    code: 'test',
    entityName,
  };

  const b: Partial<MockInstance<'setup'>> = {
    id: 1,
    code: 'test',
    entityName,
  };

  console.log(a, b);
};
```

So I have narrowed down to the fact that Partial does not behave like I would expect when dealing with generics, I am fearing this could be considered as a bug...

Thank you for any light regarding this issue.

Comment: ① Please [edit] your code to use conventional names for types; they should be in UpperCamelCase to distinguish them from lowerCamelCase values.

Comment: ② You are expecting TS to see that, no matter what `K` is, that `Partial<MockInstances[K]>>` will be `{id?: number, code?: string}`. But TS cannot abstract over `MockInstances` that way.  The only facility TS has for this is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where the types are curated so that such relationships are explicitly represented. If I do that I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mZ5JaN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thanks @jcalz for your answer, I expect Typescript to get an abstraction based on K because MockInstances is a type Record<K, Type> so if I go to MockInstance with a K I expect to get a type. If I go to MockInstance with a union of K y expect to get a union of types. In any case I have narrowed down the behaviour I do not understand, It seems related to how the Partial behaves with a mapped type accessed through a generic param. Thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript is rarely able to make higher-order conclusions about [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types. There are only specific approaches that work, and these are largely described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

---

Your `MockInstances` type is *equivalent* to `Record<MockEntityName, { id: number, code: string }>`, but they are not represented the same way.

Your version is just a manually-written-out object type, where `Record` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where it's known that the property value type is independent of the key.  The compiler would need to analyze your version and somehow recognize its equivalence to the mapped type. But it doesn't do this. Such conclusions require either human reasoning (which the compiler has yet to be able to perform) or someone programming the compiler to check for such things... meaning the compiler would spend a lot of time checking for this sort of thing in lots of places where it's useless (e.g., if you, say, modified one of the properties but not the other). Even if it were possible to do, and a common need, it might not be worth the performance hit.

If you want the compiler to know that `MockInstances`'s properties are always `{id: number, code: string}`, then you should represent it explicitly that way:

```
type MockEntityName = "app" | "setup";
type MockInstances = Record<MockEntityName, { id: number, code: string }>;
```

Next, you'd hope that the compiler would understand that, independently of `K`, that `Partial<MockInstances[K]>>` will be `{id?: number, code?: string}`.  But again, this requires a sort of generic analysis the compiler doesn't do. It would have to abstract over the nested mapped type `type PartialMockInstances<K> = Partial<MockInstances[K]>` to see that `K` doesn't matter.  And again, it cannot do this.  If you want the compiler to see that equivalence, you'll need to write it out as a mapped type over `K`:

```
type PartialMockInstances =
    { [P in MockEntityName]: Partial<MockInstances[P]> };
```

If you use IntelliSense to inspect `PartialMockInstances`, you'll see it's equivalent to

```
type PartialMockInstances = {
    app: Partial<{
        id: number;
        code: string;
    }>;
    setup: Partial<{
        id: number;
        code: string;
    }>;
}
```

So now instead of writing `Partial<MockInstances[K]>>`, you can write `PartialMockInstances[K]`, which involves [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a mapped type, about which (see microsoft/TypeScript#47109) the compiler *can* reach helpful conclusions:

```
const testWrapper = <K extends MockEntityName>() => {
    const a: PartialMockInstances[K] = {
        id: 1,
    }; // okay
};
```

Here, `PartialMockInstances[K]` is a *distributive object type* (again, see ms/TS#47109), and the compiler is happy about assigning things to those.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gYwNYFEB2wCWoByBDAW2gF4oAiPMMMqAH3IGcJgBXagbgChRJZEkAkmgbA8aBBAZRSAJQgI4AJwAmAHnjJ0WXIQgAaKAG8omZQC4oaFgQBGERQYXKIFkYsxoA5lAC+APi4eaAAFPEUsPAAbDUFhUXFJaSMoAG1gkzQ+TQxsEHwiAF0LUPDMKPV+IRExCQY0gr9fLgB6ACooIKgSiOjKuJrE0kNOAEhKMGKwntVhkZHTCytbey45pxcoNw9PVf9VplYJrqmyyJnR+fNLaztFVZH112B3L12Azh8oVubOBTiOyTAADqinG9iSqgA0lAIAAPYAQNDKKQxLS5fIQPwACgAlNJGrM-iIoHhJqUojEqvFailIQUkrNLhYAIx6UY+LgczhAA)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code:

```
const a: Partial<mockInstance<EntityName>> = {
  id: 1,
};
```

Solution:

1. Provide a more specific type hint.
2. Use type assertions.

The edited code:

```
const a: Partial<mockInstance<EntityName>> = {
    id: 1,
} as Partial<mockInstance<EntityName>>;
```

The final version code:

```
export type MockInstances = {
  app: {
    id: number;
    code: string;
  };
  setup: {
    id: number;
    code: string;
  };
};

type MockEntityName = keyof MockInstances;

type MockInstance<EntityName extends MockEntityName> =
  MockInstances[EntityName];

const testWrapper = <EntityName extends MockEntityName>() => {
  // Using type assertions to bypass the TypeScript error
  const a: Partial<MockInstance<EntityName>> = {
    id: 1,
  } as Partial<MockInstance<EntityName>>;

  const b: Partial<MockInstances[EntityName]> = {
    id: 2,
  } as Partial<MockInstances[EntityName]>;

  console.log('ab', a, b);

  // These work without issues because the type is explicitly known
  const c: Partial<MockInstance<'app'>> = {
    id: 1,
  };
  const d: Partial<MockInstances['app']> = {
    id: 2,
  };

  // Using a union type that covers all possibilities
  const e: Partial<MockInstances[MockEntityName]> = {
    id: 2,
  };

  console.log('cde', c, d, e);
};

// Remember to invoke the function with a specific type if needed
// testWrapper<'app'>(); for example
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I know that this is a solution, but I was looking for the explanation about how Typescript is unable to infer that the Partial<MockInstances<EntityName (note this is the generic param)>> is assignatble to that expression.